# @php tag in blade template can't reach inline variable

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I am looping through products which has all my configurable options available. Inside that i am looping through my items, when i get a match in product i want to display this product and item.

To do so i want to create a variable called $currentProduct.

```
@foreach($order['products'] as $product) // Configurable products
    @foreach($order['items'] as $item)  // Simple products
        @if ($item['product_type'] == 'simple')
            @if ($product['id'] === $item['product_id'])
                @php($currentProduct = $product) // error here $product undefined
                @php($currentItem = $item) // error here $item undefined
            @endif
        @elseif ($item['product_type'] == 'configurable')
            @if ($product['id'] == $item['parent_item']['product_id'])
                @php($currentProduct = $product) // error here $product undefined
                @php($currentItem = $item) // error here $item undefined
            @endif
        @endif
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

I am new to laravel and blade templates and can't seem to wrap my head around, why $product and $item is undefined when they are defined right above in same template.

Any help appreciated

Comment: I have little experience with Laravel Blade, but all the examples that I have seen enclosed the kind of code where variables were assigned between `@php` and `@endphp`. Can you try that?

Comment: Gives the same error. I dont think its a syntax problem, since the @php() is accepted. I can define other variables, i just cant reach a variable outside the @php tag

Answer (score 2):

You put the code between `@php` and `@endphp` but without parantheses.
You may have success using the `$loop` variable:

```php
@foreach($order['products'] as $product) // Configurable products
    @foreach($order['items'] as $item)  // Simple products
        @if ($item['product_type'] == 'simple')
            @if ($product['id'] === $item['product_id'])
                @php
                    $currentProduct = $order['products'][$loop->parent->index];
                    $currentItem = $order['items'][$loop->index];
                @endphp
            @endif
        @elseif ($item['product_type'] == 'configurable')
            @if ($product['id'] == $item['parent_item']['product_id'])
                @php
                    $currentProduct = $order['products'][$loop->parent->index];
                    $currentItem = $order['items'][$loop->index];
                @endphp
            @endif
        @endif
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

The variables can then be used below where they were defined.

See documentation:

- `$loop` properties: https://laravel.com/docs/master/blade#the-loop-variable
- Raw PHP in blade templates: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#raw-php

Comment: This is the wierd thing here... I can make a variable that i can access below etc. $var = 1. The problem is $product is undefined inside the php tags and therefor useless inside the php tag.

Comment: Ok I understand now. I have updated the answer. You may have success using `$loop`.

Answer (score -1):

any  @php  must close with  @endphp

Comment: Depends on laravel version. In my chase its not the problem. Wish it were that easy..

Answer (score -2):

Would you please try the below code?
`

```
@foreach($order['products'] as $product)
    @foreach($order['items'] as $item)
        @if ($item['product_type'] == 'simple')
            @if ($product['id'] === $item['product_id'])
                @php ($currentProduct = $product) @endphp
                @php ($currentItem = $item) @endphp
            @endif
        @elseif ($item['product_type'] == 'configurable')
            @if ($product['id'] == $item['parent_item']['product_id'])
                @php ($currentProduct = $product) @endphp
                @php ($currentItem = $item) @endphp
            @endif
        @endif
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

`

Comment: Give the same error. $product/ $item undefined variable

Comment: @Suresh Prajapati it is nice that you answered! However, always try to explain what you did (or your answer) instead of providing an alternative code ;)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).